# Identifying and Propagating Roadside Tree

Tags: identification, propagation, cuttings

Can anyone please tell me what species this is and how to take a cutting and propagate it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a love of strong wild and roadside plants that aren't sensitive and prone to death like **so many plants** that have died on me over the years.

Comment: Stuff like that, I usually wait for seeds. Woody plants can be hard to propagate, even when you know what they are.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger At the bottom it grows what I think are roots, as in the photos. If I cut low enough to get a few roots the will it survive and grow?

Comment: There is no way those few small roots would take up enough water for the whole tree. As a rule of thumb, the root system of a tree below ground is about the same size what is above ground - and the roots have to anchor the tree against strong wind, the weight of snow in winter, etc, as well as supply water. if you want to try cuttings, take the top 20 or 30 cm from a branch, and put half the length of it into a pot. You can put maybe 6 or 8 cuttings around the edges of pot which is *deep* enough to do that - you can separate them out after they are growing.

Comment: You could also try rooting cuttings in water. The same size and depth as in the previous comment. If you put them in a see-through container (e.g. a plastic bottle) you can see when they start to develop roots. Pot them up when the roots have grown to about 4 or 5 cm long, and be careful not to damage the roots!

Comment: @alephzero Thanks so much. Should I put rooting hormone in the water? And do you know what species this is?

Comment: @alephzero Still hoping I can find out what species it is and how often I need to water it or how else to take care of it